# Deleting row from mysql using jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to create delete feature using function and jquery

My jquery works and show messages but nothing happen "Nothing Deleted"

Jquery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".remove").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");

    if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this record?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'delete.php',
           type: 'GET',
           data: {id: id},
           error: function() {
              alert('Something is wrong');
           },
           success: function(data) {
                $("#"+id).remove();
                alert("Record removed successfully");
           }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP Function Code

```
function delete($table,$id) {
    global $connect;
    mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE `id` = $id ");
}
```

Delete.php Code

```
include ('function.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table = 'msg';
delete($table,$id);
```

HTML Code

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i        = '1';
    $username = $user_data['username'];
    $query    = "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE `go_to` = '$username' Order by id";
    $result   = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['come_from']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="read_message/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php if(count_msg_not_opened($username, $row['id']) > '0')
                    {
                        echo $row['title'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<b>' . $row['title'] . '</b>';
                    } ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I also include "jquery.min.js"

When I press "Delete" bottom this message appears "Are you sure to remove this record?"

I pressed "Yes" then this message appears "Record removed successfully", but nothing was deleted.

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: There's nothing in the PHP code that checks whether the `DELETE` was successful or that anything was deleted.

Comment: You can do even better. If you pass `0; drop table msg;` as the id, all your rows will be deleted at once! Don't use mysqli. Ever. Use PDO instead, and read up on SQL injections. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Peter No it won't. You would have to call `mysqli_multi_query()` for that to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's works .. sorry little expert in jquery

Comment: Barmar, semantics. It's still trivial to abuse the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `id` attribute to the `<tr>`

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

You should also add error checking and prepared statements to your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have connected your PHP-code to your SQL-database?

```
function delete($table,$id) {
global $connect;
mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE `id` = $id ");
}
```

The code above is relying on a connection already existing within your PHP-file. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) to find out how to apply a connection.